# Changing deployment target post launch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I released an iPhone app with deployment target of ios8.2 accidentally, I wanted it to work with ios7.

I have two questions
1. Is there any way to easily change this or do I need to release a new app version
2. If a new version needs to be released do I need to test this on a real iPhone running iOS7 i.e. do I need to downgrade my test phone before I can submit this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app isn't approved yet, you can remove it from review in the app's page in iTunes Connect, and submit a new build.

If the app is approved already, you have to create a new version to submit a new build.

In testing, you can test the app on the simulator, and if needs some real iPhone components, you can test on iOS devices 7.0 or above. You don't have to downgrade since the app will work on iOS 7.0 and above. However, there can be some bugs in older iOS versions, where devices with older versions can be useful (but you can't downgrade your devices - Apple prevents it). To test it on older versions, you need a device which hasn't been updated yet, or older versions of the simulator which Apple provides in Xcode (Check Xcode Preferences -> Downloads)